# Time period of sine wave

Tags: matlab, sine

I need to plot the time period of sine wave (wt) in rad. Am using

```
                         `rad = asin (complex(Vm));`
```

for getting the angle in rad. While plotting the MATLAB takes 180 deg as 0, 270 deg as -90 and 360 as 0. How can I get the time period within 0 to (2*pi). I have attached the scope output of the above equation.
[image]

Comment: matlab is , I think, unwrap(), but if that's not the name, there's a function that does that, just google.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. It is likewise unclear what you are showing. That does not look like a plot of `asin()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time period of a sine wave can be obtained by using a PLL block in simulink. The output from "wt" of the block will be time period in radians. [image]